# Crystal Reports SetDatasource is incredibly slow

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Here's the situation:

I've got a report that was created in Crystal Reports.  The report was created using an XSD that was generated from a DataSet - the same DataSet that is used to populate the report.  It contains a significant number of tables.

I've tried calling SetDataSource on the report and pass in an entire DataSet, but most of the fields do not appear to be populated, despite there being values in the DataSet.  I can verify this through the debugger - the values being passed into the report are fine.  There is a potential problem with how the DataSet is being mapped withing Crystal Reports itself.

To get around this, I am trying to call report.SetDataSource() for each table.  This is turning out to be brutally slow - each call to SetDataSource is taking > 20 seconds.  With 100+ tables in the DataSet, this is totally unacceptable.  From what I have been able to figure out, there could be a few reasons for this:

1. Calling SetDataSource is the slowest way of generating a Crystal Report.  Unfortunately switching it to something else at this point is no longer an option.
2. The call to SetDataSource causes Crystal Reports to attempt to authenticate with some sort of certificate server, as described here:

http://bonkel.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/crystal-reports-slow-load-using-net-c-setdatasource/

Unfortunately I have no way of verify things.  My local firewall is turned off, but it's possible that there is some other corporate firewall in the way.

Either way, there's a problem - either something is wrong with how Crystal is pulling in data from the DataSet or there is a problem with Crystal taking forever to process a SetDataSource call.

Anyone have any thoughts on this, and what I might do to either get things mapped properly or speed things up?

Comment: If you are passing 100+ tables to a report, something is drastically wrong. I can think of no valid report that needs 100+ tables. You need to write a query to return only the data you need for the report in ideally 1, maybe 2 or 3, tables.

Comment: There isn't much I can do about it at this point.  The report is a single page that has to display a bunch of values from a bunch of different tables.  The query for it would be an absolute nightmare.

Comment: Maybe a bit more info on that:  At best I could see it being narrowed down to 25 or so tables.  That still doesn't explain why the data isn't showing when calling SetDataSource and passing in just the DataSet.

Comment: I do agree with you that passing in 100+ data tables is a terrible thing, but I don't see any other way of doing it without having some really really really big stored procedures.

Comment: Are you pushing or pulling records from database? How many records does sql, that populates report, return?

Comment: I'm pulling records from a database, yes. It is generally only one record per table.

Comment: Regardless of how many tables there are, why the heck is it taking 20+ seconds to call SetDataSource on a single table (a table with only a single row and 20 or so columns)?

Comment: It's taking so long because you are basically pulling in the entire database into memory to generate the report. Write the monster stored procedure instead. This is currently the wrong way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Well guys, it looks like that is what I'll be doing.  I appreciate the help.